Intermittent Remote Desktop Connection issue: PC to PC, PC to VM, and PC to server
We’re currently experiencing an intermittent issue  Remote Desktop Connection that users are unable to connect to PCs, VMs, or servers in these scenarios:

Users from Citrix to their office PCs
Users from their office desktops to VMs
Admins from their office PCs to internal servers

Connecting using FQDN fails, using the IP address works.
We use DUO SSO when connecting to all devices and a lockout is triggered after failed attempts.
After five failed attempts the user account is not locked and it does not register on the connection target host in the audit logs or in the DUO AuthProxy server logs.
DNS resolution is clean with AD not generating any replication or resolution errors, same for LDAP.
We attempted the following without results and have ruled out it being a DNS issue:

Flushdns/registerdns
Changing DNS servers of the client
Updating the RDC client locally
Ran DISM and sfc scan/healthcheck/repair

But we did find that the Remote Desktop app from the Microsoft Store works. We added a server we were having this issue with and connected to it. We then connected to a server that wasn’t an issue connecting using the local Windows 10 RDC client. We ran qwinsta /server: xxx for both servers and saw this. The top session is using the RD from the MSFT Store and bottom is using the native client:
qwinsta_results
We’re currently researching if we can replicate the “TYPE” result (rdpwd) using the local RDC client but haven’t been able to at this point.
We also tried this GitHub article to capture communications of the RDC client – RDS session connectivity troubleshooting guidance but it’s failing on the "-scenario" statement
Thanks in advance for any insight to this issue.

This resolved it. Editing the RDP settings and saving it as the Default.rdp file disables NLA which doesn't create any security risks for us so it works.
https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/rdp-0x80004005-2578.html
